# Using ViewModel with SQLite database and not Room database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a major concern. I just read about the android `ViewModel` as a better alternative to surviving orientation changes in android and a way to reduce boilerplate codes. I have an existing project done with `SQLite` and `LoaderManager` and would like to migrate from the use of `Loaders` to `ViewModel`. However all the tutorials and docs I find online always uses `ViewModel` with `Room` Library.

I cant afford to start learning Room and my project will be very difficult to refactor in order to support Room.

Hence goes my question:

1. Can I use raw `SQLite` with `ViewModel`?
2. Was `ViewModel` designed to work only with `Room` database?

Comment: if you have done Json Object mapping to Java objects using GSON or other libraries then it will be easy for you to learn ROOM as well, i would recommend you to learn Room, if you don't have experience with above part, then it's not really difficult at all. you can find google codelab here. ViewModel Codelab -> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#0  Room Codelab -> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use raw SQLite with ViewModel?

Yes, as `ViewModel` has nothing to do with any particular source of data.

> Was ViewModel designed to work only with Room database?

No. They are completely independent.

Comment: very true., Thanks  :)

Comment: Please how then can I use view model with raw sqlite?. I need code examples

Comment: @Urchboy: "Please how then can I use view model with raw sqlite?" -- in many apps, a `ViewModel` does not use either Room or raw SQLite. Instead, a `ViewModel` talks to a repository object. The repository is responsible for talking to the data store (local database, Web service, etc.) using whatever makes sense (raw SQLite, Room, Retrofit, etc.). The repository's API hides all of those details. This is discussed a little bit in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).